# I believe there is an error in the query on how i insert info into the database for update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wamp

> the program is supposed to use a form to update a database
>
> > I removed the query that updates the table and then the page came up, i have a preset checker that checks whether the ID/ISBN parameter is posted that redirects me to an error page, when i take out the query for update the page shows up and when i add it i am redirected to the page
>
> This is the code i believe to have the error

```
$sql = "UPDATE books SET ISBN=?,Title=?,PubDate=?,PubID=?,Cost = ?, Retail = ?, Category = ? WHERE books.ISBN='$isbn'";

  if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
        $stmt->bind_param("issiiis", $isbn, $title,$pubdate,$pubid,$cost,$retail,$category);
            
            // Set parameters
            $ISBN = $isbn;
            $Title = $title;
            $PubDate = $pubdate;
            $PubID = $pubid;
            $Cost = $cost;
            $Retail = $retail; 
            $Category = $category;

            
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                echo "starting query";
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                
                  header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else
            {
                echo $stmt->error; //"Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        
            
        }
        // Close statement  
        $stmt->close(); 
    }
```

> on another not this is the query that gets the information from the database

```
    // Check existence of student_ID parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["ISBN"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["ISBN"])))
    {
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["ISBN"]);
               
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE ISBN = ?";
        
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_id);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_id = $isbn;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                
                if($result->num_rows == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set
                    contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    
                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $ISBN = $row["ISBN"];
                    $Title= $row["Title"];
                    $PubDate = $row["PubDate"];
                    $PubID = $row["PubID"];
                    $Cost = $row["Cost"];
                    $Retail = $row["Retail"];
                    $Category = $row["Category"];
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    // URL doesn't contain valid student_ID. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: error.php");
                    exit();
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        
        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();
        
        // Close connection
        $mysqli->close();
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain student_ID parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
}
```

> > I apologise in advanced for the amount of the code and my ignorance but this is very important

Comment: This is a long post.

Comment: You need to simplify the issue. There is too much code here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: done and done, i have the two queries i believe to have the issue posted

Answer (score 0):

Is your types string correct?

You're passing 'issiiis' so ISBN is being passed as an integer. In the where clause though you're treating it as a string which seems more likely given the dashes and possible leading zeroes?

Comment: thank you i did not notice, what do you recommend i do?

Comment: I would store an ISBN as a string so stick with that and just change your types string to 'sssiiis'

Comment: attempted it, no luck